# How to Alternate Content in a WPF UserControl between PasswordBox and TextBox?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio, styling

I've been working on a practice WPF project and stumbled on a question, how can I alternate just one element in a custom user control?

The project is for practice with VisualStateManager class and effects, so I've made a mock up login window with user name and password input boxes. The effect is at normal state, a textblock showing "User Name" and "Password" would be covering the TextBox and PasswordBox inside a Canvas, but once the user mouse enters the area the covering text will shrink in font size and move just above the TextBox and PasswordBox respectively.

The VisualStateManager works just fine for me, but I have a huge problem.

I tried to define a Custom User Control with all the visual transition effects defined, but I cannot come up with a good way so that the Custom User Control **alternates** between a **PasswordBox** and a **TextBox**.

I wish that it could be similar to syntax as below:

```
<window ...>
    <local:HoverOverInputControl OverlayText="User Name" ControlType="TextBox"/>
    <local:HoverOverInputControl OverlayText="Password" ControlType="PasswordBox"/>
    ...
</window>
```

And then it just displays TextBox and PasswordBox as the predefined input area respectively.

My current method is to defined two custom user controls, one called HoverOverTextBox, the other HoverOverPasswordBox. However, their code are largely the same with the only difference being one with a PasswordBox and the other TextBox as their control that handles user input (and other minute diference, e.g. when judging if the input already contain text one uses TextBox.Text.Length and the other PasswordBox.Password.Length).

Here is the code structure that might help with understanding the question in my current project:
https://github.com/moauris/HoverTextBoxDemo.git

Some experimentation that I had already went through:

- Tried to use the UserControl to set its content, did work, but soon found out that even though TextBox and PasswordBox behave almost the same but Textbox is of base type TextBoxBase and PasswordBox is of base type Control; but for properties like "Padding" cannot be defined in Control types
- Even if I managed to place a PasswordBox or a TextBox inside of my UserControl using ContentPresenter, I cannot style them in my UserControl, I must style them from outside. That means I cannot set their VisualStateManager conveniently
- I have a working version of the application, but I just have this itch knowing these two UserControls Share so many code in common but cannot be customized to behave the way I want them to

Any suggestion, idea, thought is welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: _"Custom User Control alternates between a PasswordBox and a TextBox."_ -- frankly, while I can guess, your post does not actually make clear what you even mean by this. Please fix the question so that it includes a [mcve] (pay attention to both "complete" and "minimal"...the above code is neither), and explain _precisely_ what the code you posted does, how that's different from what you want, and what _specifically_ you need help with.

Comment: Did you try placing them in 2 DataTemplates in your custom control Resources, and load them into a ContentPresenter, based on the value of property ControlType?

Comment: @o_w Thanks for the suggestion. I tried something similar, that is putting two controls and toggle their visibility and hittest to true and false based on the selection. But there is a catch: I need to acquire the PasswordBox versus TextBox content length property to make sure the overlay text don't collapse when there is text inside.

Comment: You could supply 2 new Dependency Properties for the inner controls' styles, so developer can assign them from outside.

Comment: Please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-website-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it. Posting code to github is not useful, nor does it comply with the site standards. Again, please read [mcve]. See also [ask] for more information on how to present your question in a clear, answerable way.

Comment: You can create a costom control TextBox to implement the function, then make a style for  this custom TextBox to let it use as a PasswordBox when `ControlType="PasswordBox"`.